# How to implement the $\tt conv(x,h)$ in MATLAB without using loop?

Tags: matlab, convolution, deconvolution

I'm trying to calculate convolution of two given vectors in MATLAB without using loop, and of course without the function `conv` itself, but I can't remove the last loop I've used in the code below. Any hint would be appreciated.

```
function [ convolve ] = myconv( x,y)
%This function calculate the convolution of the two inputs
lx=length(x);
ly=length(y);
lt=lx+ly;
x=[x zeros(1,ly)];
y=[y zeros(1,lx)];
convolve=zeros;
for n=2:lt
    convolve(n-1)=sum(x(1:n-1).*fliplr(y(1:n-1)));
end
```

Comment: general programming questions are offtopic here (might be better on StackOverflow, if improved), and asking for code written to a specification is also off-topic here; I don't really know what to salvage from this question, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about this:

```
function [convolve] = myconv(x, y)
    L = length(x) + length(y) - 1
    convolve = ifft(fft(x, L) .* fft(y, L));
end
```

Using the convolution theorem.

Regarding deconv function, check this out:

```
x = randn(10,1);
y = randn(10,1);

L = length(x) + length(y) - 1;

z = ifft(fft(x, L) .* fft(y, L));
z2 = conv(x, y);
sum(abs(z-z2))

x2 = ifft(fft(z, L) ./ fft(y, L));
x3 = deconv(z, y);
x0 = [x; zeros(L-length(x),1)];
sum(abs(x0-x2))
sum(abs(x3-x))
```

Program output:

```
ans =

   1.1616e-14

ans =

   5.4956e-15


ans =

   2.3924e-12
```

The first sum calculates the deviation between conv and my proposal. The second sum shows difference between the Fourier-Domain decovonvoled sequence and original sequence (note that the output of the FFT has L samples, where the last L-len(x) samples are 0). The third sum compares the output of deconv and the original sequence. You see that they all match up to floating point errors.

Comment: Yeah,I think that is the best,just one question,Is it also true for deconvolution ,I mean is$ deconv=ifft(fft(h)./fft(x))$,if $ h=conv(x,y)$.I tried  but got different answers?Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's better to explicitly constraint the output of the **ifft** to be **real** in case for for real inputs, as many implementations will treat it as **complex** valued due to very small roundoff errors introduced which practically being nonzero formally yields imaginary components...

Comment: @Fat32 that's correct. But I think, the OP should be able to do this on his own, in case it's a real signal (it's not stated its real).

Comment: @MAh2014 In principle this should work also. But, take care of the fft lengths, so it should be y=ifft(fft(h, L) ./ fft(x, L));

Comment: @Fat32, Yes that's right I'm dealing with real signals,but how could I get the exact answer?

Comment: convolve = real(ifft(fft(x, L) .* fft(y, L)));

Comment: @MAh2014 what do you mean by **exact** answer. Btw if you know that you will certainly deal with real inputs then you should better constraint the result of **ifft** to be real as in my comment.

Comment: the result isn't identical to the result of deconv function itself yet(after using real),but I will work on it ,Thank you for your hints.

Comment: The reason they are not identical is because what was shown actually is the circular convolution. To make it the exact answer just zero pad x and y and it should match.

Comment: Also what is missing but very important is to take the complex conjugate of one of the FFT's before multiplying. This may also be the reason the answers did not match. The circular convolution is ifft(fft(a).*conj(fft(b)). And zero pad as I described if you do not want it to be circular convolution.  @MaximilianMatthé I edited your answer if you approve/agree.

Comment: @DanBoschen I have to disagree to both comments: I do zero-padding of the signals, because I calculate the length of the resulting sequence beforehand and zero-pad accordingly (see variable L). So, it's a linear convolution. Second, the convolution theorem is F(x*y)=F(x)F(y), there is no conjugation contained. With conjugation, it would amount to correlation. I have thus reverted your edit.

Comment: @MAh2014 I have add some test code to verify that deconv and the fft-version yield the same result, and they do.

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé yes! My mistake, I was mistaking correlation and convolution and now see your zero-padding. Good answer!

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé Yes thank you,The problem was that the deconv function separate the quotient and the reminder,so the answers wouldn't match in those cases with reminder that is not zero.